# Print array element by name

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

```
[["RESULT", "1"], ["RESPMSG", "User authentication failed"]]
```

I want to access the `RESPMSG` element of the array and print its value, which can change, but its name is constant.

Any idea how I can print the array element by name? I tried like this, but I miss something:

```
decoded = URI::decode_www_form(@response_body, enc=Encoding::UTF_8)
respmsg = decoded.index("RESPMSG")
puts respmsg
```

The main problem is that `RESPMSG` is not always at the position `1` in the array, otherwise would be easier.

Comment: To clarify, could you be wanting to use a `Hash` instead? If you're trying to print out the value of `"RESULT"` as `1` then a Hash is almost definitely what you're looking for. If this is the case, let me know and I'll leave an answer.

Comment: Yes, I thought about hash, all I need to do is to access the value of the "RESULT" element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a hash structure to access the value for "RESPMSG"

```
respmsg = Hash[decoded]["RESPMSG"]
```

Comment: It would be good to explain why a Hash would be the better choice over an Array. Also, using `Hash[...]` is somewhat deprecated in Ruby v2+ since Array now has [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

Comment: @theTinMan `Hash::[]` is definitely not depreciated and I would dare to say it is preferable on something like SO where you cannot guarantee the OP's or any particular visitor's Ruby version. Due to its compatibility I would highly recommend this syntax since it is supported across all versions and I doubt it will reach depreciation status any time soon.

Comment: "is _somewhat_ deprecated". The italics are significant. I agree, backwards compatibility is important, but for new code running on current Ruby it's a non-issue.